# Using lag in mutate() on a arranged data

Tags: r, date, lag, lubridate, dplyr

I am working on a data set which is similar to

```
data <-tribble(
  ~id, ~ dates, ~days_prior,
  1,20190101, NA,
  1,NA, 15,
  1,NA, 20,
  2, 20190103, NA,
  2,NA, 3,
  2,NA, 4)
```

I have the first date for each ID and I am trying to calculate the next date by adding days_prior to the previous date. I am using the lag function to refer to the previous date.

```
 df<- df%>% mutate(dates = as.Date(ymd(dates)), days_prior =as.integer(days_prior))


 df<-df %>% mutate(dates =
   as.Date(ifelse(is.na(days_prior),dates,days_prior+lag(dates)),
   origin="1970-01-01"))
```

This works but only for the next row as you can see attached data.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I would like all the dates to be calculated by mutate(). What different approach should I take to calculate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really see how `lag` would help here; unless I misunderstood here is an option using `tidyr::fill`

```
data %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(dates = as.Date(ymd(dates))) %>%
    fill(dates) %>%
    mutate(dates = dates + if_else(is.na(days_prior), 0L, as.integer(days_prior))) %>%
    ungroup()
## A tibble: 6 x 3
#     id dates      days_prior
#  <dbl> <date>          <dbl>
#1     1 2019-01-01         NA
#2     1 2019-01-16         15
#3     1 2019-01-21         20
#4     2 2019-01-03         NA
#5     2 2019-01-06          3
#6     2 2019-01-07          4
```

Or a slight variation, replacing the `NA` entries in `days_prior` with 0

```
data %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(
        dates = as.Date(ymd(dates)),
        days_prior = replace(days_prior, is.na(days_prior), 0)) %>%
    fill(dates) %>%
    mutate(dates = dates + as.integer(days_prior)) %>%
    ungroup()
```

---

### Update

In response to your clarifications in the comments, here is what you can do

```
data %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(
        dates = as.Date(ymd(dates)),
        days_prior = replace(days_prior, is.na(days_prior), 0)) %>%
    fill(dates) %>%
    mutate(dates = dates + cumsum(days_prior)) %>%
    ungroup()
## A tibble: 6 x 3
#     id dates      days_prior
#  <dbl> <date>          <dbl>
#1     1 2019-01-01          0
#2     1 2019-01-16         15
#3     1 2019-02-05         20
#4     2 2019-01-03          0
#5     2 2019-01-06          3
#6     2 2019-01-10          4
```

Comment: Apologies if I didnt explain clearly. Each new date is a addition of previous date and the current prior days. So the 3rd row would have a date of 16 Jan (prev row) + 20 days (current row). 4th row would stay as is because no prior dates and 5th row would be 3rd Jan + 3 days = 6th Jan, 6th row will be calculated as 6th Jan + 4 days = 10th Jan

Comment: I see @DeepikaMantri; this seems to be a simple case of `cumsum`, see my update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `na.locf` from the `zoo` package to fill in the last observed date before adding the prior days.

```
library("tidyverse")
library("zoo")
data %>%
  # Fill in NA dates with the previous non-NA date
  # The `locf` stands for "last observation carried forward"
  # Fill in NA days_prior with 0
  mutate(dates = zoo::na.locf(dates),
         days_prior = replace_na(days_prior, 0)) %>%
  mutate(dates = lubridate::ymd(dates) + days_prior)
```

This solution makes two assumptions:

1. The rows are sorted by `id`. You can get around this assumption with a `group_by(id)` followed by an `ungroup()` statement as shows in the solution by Maurits Evers.
2. For each id, the row with the observed date is first in the group. This needs to be true in any case with either `na.locf` and `fill` because both functions fill in NAs using the previous non-NA entry.

If you don't want to make any assumptions about the ordering, you can sort the rows at the start with `data %>% arrange(id, dates)`.

Comment: I don't see how this is different from the solution(s) I posted earlier. All you do is use `zoo::na.locf` instead of `tidyr::fill` (which is one additional and in this case unnecessary package dependency), and `replace_na` instead of `replace(..., is.na(...))`; all in all, it's the same approach.

Comment: It is slightly different? Depends on the "different-ness" scale? I admit that I was confused by your `group_by`/`ungroup` statement. I thought it wasn't necessary.

Comment: And I admit that `tidyr::fill` seems like the better option. I didn't know about it.